# NGINX Crossed Mappings

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I appear to have a issue with my mappings in my NGINX configuration.

The first mapping handles UserID or Username.

The second mapping overrides the first mapping, and is forcing token in place of id or username. This second mapping should **only** handle two types of string hashes we use to authenticate.

```
Both mappings allow 2 types of parameters each.
```

**First Mapping Expected**

```
example.com/user/1/   *OR*   example.com/user/Jonny/
```

**Actual Result (ID & Username)**

```
/user/token/    =>    $_GET['token'] should not be here (its NULL)
```

**Second Mapping Expected**

```
example.com/access/SHA1-HASH/   *OR*   example.com/access/OTHER-ENC/
```

**Actual Result (Both Requests)**

```
Requests for /access/* work perfectly fine.
```

**Our NGINX config (the relevant stuff)**

```
map $id $user {
    ~^\d+$   id;
    default  username;
}

map $password $auth {
    ~^\d+$   password;
    default  token;
}

server {
    rewrite ^/access/([^/]*)/(?<password>[^/]+)/$ /download.php?$auth&$auth=$password;
    rewrite ^/user/(?<id>[^/]+)/$ /user.php?$user&$user=$username
}
```

**I want to support both mappings.**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify "I tried renaming variables". What was the exact configuration you tried?

Comment: I noticed that too. I tried renaming the first "$id_type" => $user_type, and renamed second "$id_type" => $auth_type, so see if "$id_type" was conflicting with both types of requests. It had no effect and the problem remained.

Comment: Please add the exact configuration you tried to the question, the HTTP requests you made and the responses you received.

Comment: ```Post updated for clarity```

Comment: There are still the duplicate `$id_type` map declarations here, which cannot work. Please show the attempt where you renamed the variables and corresponding results.

Comment: Post updated. Do you have any NGINX suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`$username` variable is not defined here, that is one issue at least.

Otherwise I don't see why this configuration would do the effect you are describing.

With the rules above `GET /user/1234/` is rewritten to `/user.php?id&id=$username`.